# What is the 'right' way of deleting array elements in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array containing a set of elements. The order of elements is irrelevant - I use an array since it's the simplest data structure I know in Perl.

```
my @arr = ...
while (some condition) {
    # iterate over @arr and remove all elements which meet some criteria
    # (which depends on $i)
}
```

I know of `splice()` but I think it's not good using it while iterating. `delete` for array elements seems deprecated. Perhaps use `grep` on `@arr` into itself (`@arr = grep {...} @arr`)?

What is the best practice here?

Perhaps use a hash (although I don't really need it)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to delete a value from an array in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174292/what-is-the-best-way-to-delete-a-value-from-an-array-in-perl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea of using grep is good

```
@arr = grep { cond($i++); } @arr;
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the docs, calling [`delete`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html) on array values is deprecated and likely to be removed in a future version of Perl.

Alternatively, you can build a list of needed indices and assign the slice to the original array:

```
@arr = @arr[ @indices ];
```

You can read more about slices in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).